# Passing a variable from an external javascript file onto a value in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a "shopping form" where I can edit prices in an external .js file by changing a single variable from the .js, and will be reflected in a value within my html that totals up the total cost.

The Javascript file, called "prices.js"

```
var x = "100.00";
var y = "200.00";
```

My html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Banana for Sale">
<input class="amount" type="hidden" name="amount_1" value=x>

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Orange for Sale">
<input class="amount" type="hidden" name="amount_2" value=y>
```

Essentially, I'm trying to pass the "x" and "y" variable from my external javascript onto the "values" in my html for each item. I'm a complete noob at this, so the above obviously isn't working.

Just to clarify, I don't need the code to write the value immediately, only to change the value so that it can be written by another function (which is already taken care of) that totals up all of the amounts from all items above.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: add to your script `document.getElementByTagName('input').value = x;`

Comment: you can also use `getElementById`

Comment: use `document.getElementByTagName('input')[0].value = x;` to specify element number

Comment: You can use the `class` selector since the input has already a class `amount`, example : `$('.amount').val(x);`, see answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getElementsByName` to find your hidden variable and then you can populate it with the value of `x`. The JavaScript below needs to be saved to your `prices.js` file. Just to clarify, `getElementsByName` is returning an array, so I am taking the first entry to be able to set the `value` field.

```js
x = 10
y = 5
document.getElementsByName("amount_1")[0].value = x
document.getElementsByName("amount_2")[0].value = y
document.write(document.getElementsByName("amount_1")[0].value + '<br>')
document.write(document.getElementsByName("amount_2")[0].value + '<br>')
```

```html
<input class="amount" type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="">
<input class="amount" type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="">
```

Comment: Hi, I edited my original post to clarify things. Sorry about not being able to articulate my question better the first time. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have changed the code to use `getElementsByName` so you can have two inputs with the same class name.

Comment: I've tried it, but it's still not working for some reason.

To explain the code better, I was previously able to set the "values" as a number (i.e. 5) and when I clicked on a (+1) button next to the item, it would add the number to the total automatically and show it.

Comment: ^Edited my comment above to explain it better. Thank you so much!

Comment: Nevermind, I don't know why but I got it to work based on your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign variables to the `inputs` using `.val()` and `class` selector, e.g :

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.amount_1').val(x);
        $('.amount_2').val(y);
    })
</script>
```

Hope this helps.